# Vue/Nuxt and Django Stack, How to make a local request to my Django API on server?

Tags: django, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm working on an app using Vue and Nuxt, I want to send a request from my Vue app, to my Django app (Which is running on the same machine).

Nuxt just sends the request on the client side to localhost but I want to do that from my Nuxt app to my Django app, how can I do that?

when I send an axios request to fetch some data from my django api, it sends it from the client, not from the server "to" my django app which also is on the same server.

I want that request to be completely local on the server and my api to NOT be accessible from anywhere else.

Comment: Nuxt is probably not the framework you're looking for if you want only some server side requests. Since Nuxt is isomorphic, it will run on the server then on the client, since it's pretty much aimed towards a client side usage (VueJS).

Answer (score 0):

you can use Nuxt server

[Nuxt 2 Server middlewares](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware/)
[Nuxt 3 Server routes](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/features/server-routes)

check out these links
Basically send request to your Nuxt server routes an then to your Django API

Comment: Links-only answers are not allowed here.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).